# How does Kaya's Ghostform interact with Elenda, the Dusk Rose?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have [Elenda, the Dusk Rose](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElenda%2c%20the%20Dusk%20Rose%5d) in play, enchanted with [Kaya's Ghostform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKaya%27s%5d%2b%5bGhostform%5d). My opponent has a zombie creature token.

I then cast [Kaya's Wrath](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKaya%27s%5d%2b%5bWrath%5d), destroying Elenda and the zombie.

When the zombie dies, Elenda's ability goes on the stack, intending to giving her a +1/+1 counter. Since Elenda just died, normally this would do nothing (the ability can't find its target as it resolves).

But can I, as Elenda's controller, choose to resolve [Kaya's Ghostform](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKaya%27s%5d%2b%5bGhostform%5d) first, returning Elenda to the battlefield, then resolve her triggered ability, giving her the +1/+1 counter? Or is the Elenda that returns "different" from the Elenda whose ability was triggered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can indeed choose which ability resolves first, but it won't help you.

> Or is the Elenda that returns "different" from the Elenda whose ability was triggered?

Yes, this is exactly what is going on. The [rules](https://media.wizards.com/2019/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020190612.txt) state:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

There follow nine exceptions to this rule but the situation caused by Kaya's Ghostform isn't one of them.

Comment: Ah, alas. So if I understand right, the triggered ability is looking for a specific entity to put the counters on, and that entity has permanently ceased to exist?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I have looked at rule 608 but I can't find a subrule that specifically applies to this situation (since Elenda's ability doesn't target).